# refresh table view after remove subview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a table view and when I select any row then add a view as a sub view. In sub view I have a button. now I want that when I click on that button then my subview will remove and table view also refresh and some data of main view will also updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in various ways:

1. You can use delegate.
2. Reload tableview in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2):

Use Delegation.
Remove sub view and call delegate method and use [tableView reloadData]; in delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

when you touch on your button , use the following methods:

```
[yourView removeFromSuperView];
[yourTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[yourTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```